# Delete all files in a folder having timestamp in filename

Tags: command-line, files, delete

I have to remove all the files in a folder whose file names have `fcrjlog-11-21-2019-1.txt` format. I want to remove all the files having this kind of filename in a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 find . ! -type d -name 'fcrjlog-??-??-????-?.txt' -delete
```

(replace `-delete` with `-exec rm -f {} +` if your `find` doesn't support the non-standard `-delete` extension).

`?` is the wildcard operator that stands for *any single character*. Replace with `[[:digit:]]` to only match on decimal digit characters (0123456789).

`! -type d` excludes the files of type *directory* (which `-delete` could not remove unless they were empty anyway), you can replace with `-type f` to be even more restrictive (only include *regular* files to the exception of all other types of files including symlink, directory, socket, fifo, device...). GNU `find` also supports `-xtype f` to select the files that are determined to be *regular* after symlink resolution.

Replace `fcrjlog` with `*` to match on any number of characters, or `?*` for any non-empty sequence of characters, or `[!.]*` for any non-empty sequence of characters the first of which is not `.` (to exclude hidden files).

Comment: Don't we need to mention  path of the folder in which those files are present?

Comment: @VAMSEEKRISHNATATIKONDA, yes, in my example, it's `.`, the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's customary to display some of the things you've already tried - you'll get more responses that way.  For this question, you need to lookup regular expressions, and understand some of the concepts.  I assume the "x" in your timestamps are numbers?  If so, this regular expression will get you started:

```
/tmp>ls | grep -E "[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{1}.txt$"
test-12-12-1234-9.txt

/tmp>rm $(ls | grep -E "[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{1}.txt$")
```

Breaking down the various pieces:

```
"
 [0-9]{2}  -- Exactly two numeric characters
 -         -- A literal dash "-"
 [0-9]{2}  -- Exactly two numeric characters
 -         -- A literal dash "-"
 [0-9]{4}  -- Exactly four numeric characters
 -         -- A literal dash "-"
 [0-9]     -- One numeric character
 .         -- Any character.  Use \. to insist on a dot
 txt       -- The literal string "txt"
 $         -- An anchor that means the txt has to be at the end of the line
"
```

Comment: @AdminBee, _never parse the output of ls_ which here translates to: it won't work properly if there are filenames that contain characters of `$IFS` or newline or wildcard characters or start with `-`. We might add that `[0-9]` is only guaranteed to match on 0123456789 in the POSIX locale (outside of that in practice, it often matches a lot more), or that `-` is not special (outside of bracket expressions) in REs so should *not* be escaped. It's better to use single quotes than double quotes around things that contain backslashes or `$`.